# Linux Kernel Panic "No working init found", at building own distro using BUSYBOX

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I started to build my own distro, with busybox. i use kernel 5.15 self compiled. already created an initramfs. this is the init script of initramfs:

```
    #!/bin/sh
    /bin/sh
```

now if i startup this using qemu with:

```
    qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel kernel_5.15 -initrd initrd.img
```

i get an kernel panic:

```
    [    1.765830] Run /init as init process
    [    1.767253] Failed to execute /init (error -2)
    [    1.767516] Run /sbin/init as init process
    [    1.768032] Run /etc/init as init process
    [    1.768338] Run /bin/init as init process
    [    1.768656] Run /bin/sh as init process
    [    1.769230] Kernel panic - not syncing: No working init found.  Try passing init= option to     kernel. See Linux Documentation/admin-guide/init.rst for guidance.
    [    1.770061] CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 5.15.145 #1
    [    1.770416] Hardware name: QEMU Standard PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996), BIOS 1.15.0-1 04/01/2014
    [    1.770914] Call Trace:
    [    1.771538]  <TASK>
    [    1.771789]  dump_stack_lvl+0x34/0x48
    [    1.772223]  ? memcpy_orig+0x110/0x123
    [    1.772421]  panic+0xfb/0x2b2
    [    1.772563]  ? kernel_execve+0x14b/0x190
    [    1.772762]  ? rest_init+0xb0/0xb0
    [    1.772933]  kernel_init+0x10e/0x110
    [    1.773095]  ret_from_fork+0x22/0x30
    [    1.773314]  </TASK>
    [    1.773789] Kernel Offset: 0x37e00000 from 0xffffffff81000000 (relocation range: 0xffffffff80000000-0xffffffffbfffffff)
    [    1.774506] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: No working init found.  Try passing init= option     to kernel. See Linux Documentation/admin-guide/init.rst for guidance. ]---
```

I also have tried to pass init paramter like init=/init. but also get an kernel panic like follows:

```
    [    1.784834] Run /init as init process
    [    1.786264] Failed to execute /init (error -2)
    [    1.786513] Run /init as init process
    [    1.787051] Kernel panic - not syncing: Requested init /init failed (error -2).
    [    1.787507] CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 5.15.145 #1
    [    1.787853] Hardware name: QEMU Standard PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996), BIOS 1.15.0-1 04/01/2014
    [    1.788318] Call Trace:
    [    1.788994]  <TASK>
    [    1.789254]  dump_stack_lvl+0x34/0x48
    [    1.789656]  ? memcpy_orig+0x110/0x123
    [    1.789807]  panic+0xfb/0x2b2
    [    1.789933]  ? rest_init+0xb0/0xb0
    [    1.790071]  kernel_init+0xba/0x110
    [    1.790214]  ret_from_fork+0x22/0x30
    [    1.790396]  </TASK>
    [    1.790862] Kernel Offset: 0x7600000 from 0xffffffff81000000 (relocation range:             0xffffffff80000000-0xffffffffbfffffff)
    [    1.791676] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: Requested init /init failed (error -2). ]---
```

pls help. if you need i can give nearer information

tried:

- passing init as paramter
- changing permission of initramfs files
- other kernel
- different tutorials on youtube